Why can you not "dress trashy 'til you spend a lot of money" in "It's Still Rock and Roll to Me" by Billy Joel?
In the song "It's Still Rock and Roll to Me" Billy Joel sings a line "you can't dress trashy 'til you spend a lot of money." I do not understand what he means exactly. I have red the annotations to the lyrics on Genius.
I believe to have doubts in part because I am a nonnative English speaker. I then guess I am confused more about language than the meaning of the song itself.
An interpretation of this line that is most obvious to me is that it introduces a proverbial reality in which you spend a lot of money. Then this reality requires that, until you do it, you, for some reason unknown to me, cannot dress trashy. If you, for some reason, stopped spending it, you could start to dress trashy.
But after analyzing the lyrics, I see they suggest another interpretation, less obvious to me. It goes that Billy Joel seems to find the fashion of the then new music fashion, so to say, expensive, yet trashy.
So, the first interpretation interprets the word "'til" as "until you stop," and the second as "until you start."
Which one is correct? Or neither, or both? Can there be another one?

I am answering my own question. Although the answers explain the line itself, I think they do not address my reflections on it in enough details. Indeed, they can not, because these reflections only arose while I was reading the answers.
Let me concentrate on the first verse, first pre-chorus, and first chorus only. Other parts of the song are not relevant to the question. I am quoting the relevant parts below so we can understand the explanation better.

FIRST VERSE
What's the matter with the clothes I'm wearing?
Can't you tell that your tie's too wide?
Maybe I should buy some old tab collars?
Welcome back to the age of jive
PRE-CHORUS
Where have you been hidin' out lately, honey?
You can't dress trashy 'til you spend a lot of money
CHORUS
Everybody's talkin' 'bout the new sound
Funny, but it's still rock and roll to me

Let me start with assuming that there are three, so to say, "personas," or maybe "voices," as @Chris Sunami suggests in his answer. First is the "asking persona." It speaks the first and third lines of the verse. Second is the "pop culture irony persona." It speaks the second and fourth line of the verse, and the pre-chorus. Third is the "concluding persona." It speaks the chorus.
The narrative goes, as far as I understand it, that the asking persona starts a conversation. The interlocutor that it assumes to talk to is unidentified, I would say. Then the pop culture irony persona joins the conversation playing the role of the interlocutor, quite like the Greek chorus. Then again speaks the asking persona. Then again speaks the pop culture irony persona, this time extending its reply with the pre-chorus. Finally, in the chorus the conversation is over, and the concluding persona concludes it.
I think there are two main things that my problem with understanding the line from the question lies in. First is understanding the tones of the personas. Second is understanding how the music culture looked in the time the song was written.
Firstly the tones. I see three of them, that is, irony, naïveté and resignation. Irony is the most distinctive. It was not that obvious to me how much irony should I attribute to whom. Now I would eventually say that the pop culture irony persona is by design always ironic, even though I still do not understand exactly what it means by "welcome back to the age of jive." Also, the concluding persona partly uses irony. Naïveté is expressed by the asking persona. As for resignation, there may be a better term for this tone that I do not know. It is expressed by the concluding persona alongside of irony.
Secondly the music culture. The other answers describe it well enough. I will just quote @Chris Sunami below to conclude what I think is most relevant.

The particular lyric in question reflects a persistent American fashion reality. If you dress "trashy" people will assume that you're poor, and they'll look down on the clothing. But if they know you're rich, they'll assume you spent a lot of money to get that look, and will applaud it as a bold fashion choice. Dom already mentioned ripped jeans, an iconic example, but you could also mention trucker caps, polyester fabrics, and rumpled hair. Often, the fashionable version is a very expensive variant that is distinguishable from the cheap version only to the trained eye.

So, how should the above reflections on the tones and the music culture answer my question? The asking persona asks how it should dress to fit in the trends. On a side note, the rest of the song tells us that the asking persona is not only about dressing in this desire.
The pop culture irony persona answers how in the pre-chorus, and it does two things there. Firstly it suggests us that what the asking persona really wants is to dress trashy. The word "really" is important here. For me the question of the asking persona is general enough to assume that the asking persona is not to suggests us that it knows that trashiness is what it should seek in the clothes, or even, maybe unknowingly, does seek. Well, the thing here is that maybe I am biased because I do not know the time and culture the song was written. Maybe I just overinterpret this dialog.
Secondly the pop culture irony explains that what the asking persona does to look so is not enough. It suggests us, or at least I think it does, that it is not enough to care about how the clothes look, what I think we are to see the asking persona is doing, but also how expensive the clothes are. I now think one can truly say, what @jrw32982 is explaining in his answer and a comment to it, that the asking persona is "unable" to dress trashy until, or, equivalently, as @Chris Sunami notes in his answer, "unless" it spends a lot of money. It means that the trends expect one to spend money on clothes, ipso facto rendering one unable to fit in them without money. This "being unable to" is what I now think is the right interpretation of the "can't" from the line, as opposed to "being not allowed to," what I thought was right, and what I have mentioned in a comment to the answer of @jrw32982.
And finally, which of the two interpretations from the question should I choose? Neither as I have phrased them. I have written that "Billy Joel seems to find the fashion of the then new music fashion, so to say, expensive, yet trashy." In general you can say so, but in fact my misunderstanding lied somewhere beyond that. It is just that I could not express it rightly in the question.
I welcome if you want to improve this answer, or point out mistakes I have made.

UPDATE
I just listened to the song again, and it occurred to me I might describe it more clearly what the pop culture irony persona thinks about trashiness. Now it looks clear to me, maybe I am wrong, that the pop culture irony persona judges that the trendy clothes look trashy. Particularly ironic here is the juxtaposition of what the asking persona seeks, which seems to be just an advice, and what the pop culture irony persona provides, which is the advice together with a judgment that it is not worth following.

The verses are a dialog between a side of Billy (represented by his natural voice) that is flirting with picking up on the new trends ("call" lines, "What's the matter with the clothes I'm wearing?", "Maybe I should buy some old tab collars?), and a mocking, nasal voice that represents pop culture irony ("response" lines, "Can't you tell that your tie's too wide?", "Welcome back to the age of jive" and pre-chorus "You can't dress trashy 'til you spend loss of money"). The bridge ("you can't get the sound from a story in a magazine") and chorus are the side of Billy that sees things with more distance and perspective, and gives up on chasing trends.
The particular lyric in question reflects a persistent American fashion reality. If you dress "trashy" people will assume that you're poor, and they'll look down on the clothing. But if they know you're rich, they'll assume you spent a lot of money to get that look, and will applaud it as a bold fashion choice. Dom already mentioned ripped jeans, an iconic example, but you could also mention trucker caps, polyester fabrics, and rumpled hair. Often, the fashionable version is a very expensive variant that is distinguishable from the cheap version only to the trained eye.
"Til" here has the rough meaning of "unless," which is a little non-standard, but perfectly understandable. Out of your options "until you start" is the correct one. Your first interpretation would not be idiomatic for standard American English.

I have red the lyrics a few times. But I still do not know when exactly the protagonist speaks ironically, and when does so the chorus. I mean, the Greek chorus. Particularly I do not see whether it is the line about buying "old tab collars," or the line about welcoming back to the "age of jive," or both, or neither. I only see that ironic are the next lines, the pre-chorus. Assuming we know from the first line the opinion of the protagonist about the new trends, I would say "old tab collars" are ironic. And now I am confused also who speaks about that "age of jive." Continued.

Continued. Among these two confusions I welcome that you mention "unless." It sheds more light on the meaning, and I did not think about it. I now see that the chorus, the one who says the problematic line, is suggesting that it is not only a general rule not to dress trashy, but that it is specifically the protagonist that should not do so. No, but it is like mixing a general rule and a requirement for the protagonist… Hm.

The verses are a dialog between a side of Billy (represented by his natural voice) that is flirting with picking up on the new trends ("call" lines), and a mocking, nasal voice that represents pop culture irony ("response" lines and pre-chorus). The bridge and chorus are the side of Billy that sees things with more distance and perspective, and gives up on chasing trends.

I like your terms "flirting" and "pop culture irony." They fit here. Yes, I think I agree there are three voices in the conversation.

In general it's talking about fashion trends of Rock and Roll and the expense related to them. Whether he's specifically calling the style of the cloths "trashy" or mocking that people will to pay for trends that some may consider "trashy" is up to interpretation, but it's clear it's about fans or performers spending money on popular "trashy" fashion.
Specifically for the word 'til it is just short for the word until so the line would flow better. So you can view the line as

you can't dress trashy until you spend a lot of money

I tend to view it as a more sarcastic line since literally afterwards he says:

Everybody's talkin' 'bout the new sound Funny,
but it's still rock and roll to me

Which hints even if the new sounds of Rock are "Funny" it's still rock and roll to him which I think would follow to the fashion too.
A simple example of this would be ripped jeans which is associated with many genres since around the time of punk. You can buy your jeans already ripped and you'll typically end up paying more for the ripped look that some would call "trashy". Hence "you can't dress trashy 'til you spend a lot of money".

You do not address my "'til" confusion directly. But I can see you favor the second interpretation. But then, I wonder, is it specifically Billy Joel who finds the fashion trashy, or the society in general? In other words, who does impose the "you can now dress trashy" rule here? I too view it as sarcastic, but I still think this rule has to be imposed by someone. By the way, I just corrected a typo in the question. I had mistakenly swapped the words "start" and "stop" in the summary.

@Mike updated to talk about the til which is just short for until. For who interprets it as trashy it's not clear, but no one is imposing "you can now dress trashy" it's an observation of the state of fashion in this regard. It's saying people pay the money to look trashy either in the eye of Billy Joel or the perception of society. Which in my opinion is not as important since either way someone views it as trashy.

OK, thank you, but sorry I did not describe my confusion clearly. Yes, I know "'til" is an abbreviation of "until." I rather mean that for me "until" describes such a future point in time in which either "something new will start to be happening" or "something that is happening now will stop." I do not know which meaning the lyrics refer to. Thus my confusion about the line. But either way it is a rather linguistic thing, I think, so it may be that I overthink it. But anyway, your answer describes the second interpretation, and that is OK for me.

Haha.  You're right.  It could mean:  "you're not allowed to dress trashy until you spend a lot of money (on something)".  Or: "you are unable to dress trashy without spending a lot of money".  To a native speaker, the second one is the obvious choice, especially because the "on something" part makes no sense.
In another context though, "you can't have your pudding until you eat your meat" (to paraphrase Pink Floyd).  In this case, it means "not allowed to" rather than "unable to".  Again, you have to interpret it from context, since the "unable to" interpretation is hard to reconcile with common sense in this case.
In both cases, a necessary prerequisite is being specified, but it could be because of a physical requirement or because of a social or conventional requirement.

So, you agree with my second interpretation, but then you differentiate two cases in it, right? I thought it should rather be "not allowed." The song is about what people think, so I would say they would "not allow" Billy to dress trashy unless he spends enough money to fit in the norms, especially after reading the other two answers here. I would not add the "on something" part, maybe because I am a nonnative speaker.

I've heard this song dozens of times; the "not allowed" interpretation never occurred to me.  The 2nd interpretation seemed (and still seems) "obvious" because the song talks about someone who can't "tell that their tie's too wide".  It's not that he didn't throw his money around (1st interpretation); it's that he doesn't have the "correct, hip," style-sense and he needs to spend more money to buy the "in" clothes.  I read the other answers as agreeing with me.  It's not that he is not allowed to dress trashy, it's that he hasn't paid enough to buy the really cool clothes, like ripped jeans.

Well then! I was thinking about adding an answer myself, but your comment made me think about it a bit longer. The other answers do not suggest such interpretation to me. I think I see it… It is that Billy does dress trashy now, does he not? Then the pop culture irony advises him to reflect on it, and spend more money, should he want to fit in the trends, right? It must be I cannot imagine well enough how he looks in the eyes of the then pop culture. A too wide tie, old tab collars, and the age of jive do not paint a clear picture in my head, though I know why they are mentioned.

PS And then another aspect of it comes to my mind… You mentioned the term "unable." At first it seemed related to my first interpretation, the one I have already found incorrect. But now I think he might be unable, indeed! "Unable" if we imagine that he wants to fit in the trends, so he wants to look trashy. But he cannot, he still looks good, though he tries. So the pop culture irony advises him to just spend more money. Ironic is here the fact that simply spending more money will help Billy, that is, help to look "better" in the eyes of his contemporaries.
